# GTM and GA push data to events asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In my web application Goggle Tag Manager is used in order to take control of Google Analytics. The problem is that I cannot get it working properly.

There are 2 separate http requests to api from completely separate components:

- `GET api.com/user/:id` - called on every page
- `GET api.com/order/:id` - called only on order success page

When I receive successful order I push data in dataLayer:

```
dataLayer.push({ event, productName });
```

When I receive user I also push data in dataLayer (custom dimensions):

```
dataLayer.push({ userId });
```

But inside GTM preview debugger `userId` is always undefined and I assume it's because user request finishes later.

How to make the data correspond to each other? Or another workaround?

Comment: I hope that's pseudo code you posted :D because otherwise it won't work.  You should push an event with `dataLayer.push({userId})` so that you can then use that event to get the `userId` data.

Comment: it's pseudocode, but it's not necessary to push event if `dataLayer.push({userId})` was called before `dataLayer.push({ event, productName });`.

Comment: No, definitely not necessary, but doesn't hurt to have it either, and you would have that much more flexibility with getting the `userId` value.

Comment: I have a lot of different events that need userId, so I just make one push with user id when user is requested.

Comment: Can you describe the order of when events happen with the successful order and user? Also, what do you mean when you "receive user'. Do you mean when a user signs in?